# Primary Keys, Unique Id, and Records (MySQL, PHP, Info Systems)

Tags: php, mysql, database, primary-key, unique-id

I am creating a social networking site that will be open to the general public and will expected to host a large number of users. The information of each user will be stored in a MySQL database, and pages will be written in PHP.

My question is this: What do big sites such as Facebook, Yahoo, Stack Overflow use for their primary and unique keys to keep track of a large number of data?

For an example, a table such as:

PK,    Unique_Id,     User_Id,     F_Name,     L_Name,     Date_Created,     DEL,     etc...

How can I give each user in this table their own unique_id they can have for themselves that will be reasonable? What format should a unique id be in to be beneficial? How should I manage the primary keys? Let the pk start from 1 and increment each time?

Comment: A 32-bit integer ought to do the trick: sufficient to represent over 4 billion users; and unless you have other constraints, yes - start from 1 and count up.  `AUTO_INCREMENT` can help you here.  Alternatively, you could always make something like their email address your PK... might not scale so well though, given the size of it.

Comment: Take a look at [this paper](http://www.allthingsdistributed.com/2007/10/amazons_dynamo.html), it describes how Amazon works. Facebook, LinkedIn and others have a similar approach.

Comment: Instagram is generating their Unique IDs in their application instead of using auto-increment http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/10853187575/sharding-ids-at-instagram

Comment: Is `Unique_Id` necessary? If it's just an autogenerated field, your PK should be sufficient. If it's a user generated field (for example, Facebook let's you define a profile name so you can go to facebook.com/username) then it makes sense. Your supporting tables should all use the PK as the linking field.

Comment: Well, at first I thought a auto-incremented PK field would have been great. But, I then realized this... If I only use a primary key to identify records if I get to a million users, I would then have a primary key of 1000000. Which technically isn't bad. But what if I want a more formal way of identifying a user account. Say the user is the first to get an account is id would be "1" or "000001" but what if I want to give that user an "account number" as a unique id. What do I do then? Wouldn't this be better than just a simple primary key?

Comment: @AndrewR See previous comment.

Comment: It all depends on how you want to use `Unique_Id`. Is it meant to be how you access a users profile page, like www.example.com/user/uniqueid? If so, why wouldn't www.example.com/userid be just as good? Userid has to be a unique field.

Comment: I want to use unique_id to reference a user's account. It will be used for multiple uses besides a URL. Such as if the user creates a web ticket. Or even to reference a web ticket. What if I want a more uniform way of doing this like 201104089865. This for an example is a unique id containing the date 2011-04-08, followed by the ticket number. Can you see what I am trying to get at?

Comment: @AndrewR for the above comment.